# How do i find which config file is read when using EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<SqlDatabase>(connectionName)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library

This line `SqlDatabase sqlDatabase = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<SqlDatabase>(connectionName);`

in my application is used to retrieve connection string from config file but the problem there is nearly 4 web config files as

```
*web.config
*web.debug.config
*web.ct7.config
```

i dont know from which file the connection is retrieved. any idea how to find it out. please share.

i tried changing the values in all config files but problem is the application does not load if we change and run again. also i changed at runtime but couldnt find it out

Answer (score 0):

We can use this line of code `string config = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`.This gives the value of which config file is being retrieved & used.So if there is N layers in your application & each layer has a config file & if u want to find which config file is read the above code can be used.